# I Can't open Ports on Ubuntu-VM

Tags: ubuntu, port

I try to initialize a connection by socket between my Ubuntu-VM and Windows. The Problem is that my Ports on Ubuntu are totaly closed.
The connection is local. Ubuntu runs in VM on my Windows Client.

Ubuntu-IP: 192.168.1.64
Windows-IP: 192.168.1.192

If I start my Programm on Ubuntu, I start an active socket() where listen on Port 7777. The Ports are open in my Ubuntu firewall.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVRJi.png)

But if I try to connect the socket with my Windows Client, the connection fails with answer "10061".

I think that happens, because my Port is for Windows not open.

Nmap on my Port fails too...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCalZ.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you opened the ports on your Windows Firewall?

Comment: Hello, yes the ports are open in Windows.